# Php, chain-calling collision (magic) methods in traits, how to?

Tags: php, traits

```
trait A
{
    function __get($name)
    {
    }
}

trait B
{
    function __get($name)
    {
    }
}

trait C
{
    function __get($name)
    {
    }
}

class D
{
    use A, B, C;

    function __get($name)
    {
        // it may also have magic method
    }
}
```

I want to call all 4 `__get()` methods, is that doable? I see that I can rename methods but its rather a choosing a method from A, B, C but I need all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible without renaming the imported `__get` methods.

See PHP docs on this matter: [PHP: Traits - Conflict Resolution](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict)

```
class D
{
    use A, B, C {
        A::__get as private __getA;
        B::__get as private __getB;
        C::__get as private __getC;
    }

    function __get($name)
    {
        $this->__getA($name);
        $this->__getB($name);
        $this->__getC($name);
    }
}
```

(I've renamed the class to *D* since you cannot have a trait and a class with the same name in one namespace.)

Comment: @JohnSmith While this answer is technically correct, and will let you do what you want to do, I'm not quite sure about how good of an idea the base premise is. Do you really need to have this many magic methods, spread over so many classes? It will make the basic logic of your code a lot harder to grasp, and as such will most likely be the direct cause of a lot of bugs.